# CT_FETCH error in PowerBuilder Program

Tags: overflow, powerbuilder

I'm still learning PowerBuilder and trying to get familiar with it.  I'm receiving the following error when I try to run a program against a specific document in my database:

ct_fetch(): user api layer: internal common library error: The bind of result set item 4 resulted in an overflow. ErrCode: 2.

What does this error mean?  What is item 4?  This is only when I run this program against a specific document in my database, any other document works fine.  Please see code below:

```
string  s_doc_nmbr, s_doc_type, s_pvds_doc_status, s_sql
long        l_rtn, l_current_fl, l_apld_fl, l_obj_id
integer l_pvds_obj_id, i_count


IF cbx_1.checked = True THEN

SELECT dsk_obj.obj_usr_num, 
dsk_obj.obj_type, 
preaward_validation_doc_status.doc_status,
preaward_validation_doc_status.obj_id
INTO :s_doc_nmbr, :s_doc_type, :s_pvds_doc_status, :l_pvds_obj_id

FROM dbo.dsk_obj dsk_obj, 
preaward_validation_doc_status
WHERE dsk_obj.obj_id = :gx_l_doc_obj_id
AND preaward_validation_doc_status.obj_id =  dsk_obj.obj_id
using SQLCA;

l_rtn = sqlca.uf_sqlerrcheck("w_pdutl095_main", "ue_run_script", TRUE)  
IF l_rtn = -1 THEN
    RETURN -1
END IF

//check to see if document (via obj_id) exists in the preaward_validation_doc_status table.
SELECT count(*)
into :i_count
FROM preaward_validation_doc_status
where  obj_id = :l_pvds_obj_id
USING SQLCA;


IF i_count = 0 THEN
    //document doesn't exist
    //  messagebox("Update Preaward Validation Doc Status", + gx_s_doc_nmbr +  ' does not exist in the Preaward Validation Document Status table.', Stopsign!)
    //MC - 070815-0030-MC Updating code to insert row into preaward_validation_doc_status if row doesn't already exist
//  s_sql = "insert into preaward_validation_doc_status(obj_id, doc_status)  values (:gx_l_doc_obj_id, 'SUCCESS') "

    INSERT INTO preaward_validation_doc_status(obj_id, doc_status)
    VALUES (:gx_l_doc_obj_id, 'SUCCESS') 
    USING SQLCA;
                        IF sqlca.sqldbcode <> 0 then
                        messagebox('SQL ERROR Message',string(sqlca.sqldbcode)+'-'+sqlca.sqlerrtext)
                        return -1
                    end if

    MessageBox("PreAward Validation ", 'Document number ' + gx_s_doc_nmbr +  ' has been inserted and marked as SUCCESS for PreAward Validation.')
    return 1
Else
    //Update document status in the preaward_validation_doc_status table to SUCCESS                 
    Update preaward_validation_doc_status
    Set doc_status = 'SUCCESS'
    where  obj_id = :l_pvds_obj_id
    USING SQLCA;                        
                    IF sqlca.sqldbcode <> 0 then
                        messagebox('SQL ERROR Message',string(sqlca.sqldbcode)+'-'+sqlca.sqlerrtext)
                        return -1
                    end if
    MessageBox("PreAward Validation ", 'Document number '+ gx_s_doc_nmbr +  ' has been marked as SUCCESS for PreAward Validation.')
End IF

update crt_script
set alt_1 = 'Acknowledged' where
ticket_nmbr = :gx_s_ticket_nmbr and
alt_2 = 'Running' and
doc_nmbr = :gx_s_doc_nmbr
USING SQLCA;    

    Return 1

ElseIF cbx_1.checked = False THEN
        messagebox("Update Preaward Validation Doc Status", 'The acknowledgment checkbox must be selected for the script to run successfully. The script will now exit.  Please relaunch the script and try again . ', Stopsign!)
        Return -1
End IF
```

Comment: That message is from your database engine or driver. It would help us immensely if you narrowed down the SQL statement that is generating the error. Once you've done that, I'd run the SQL statement in an interactive tool, looking for large strings or numbers. (Not sure why you're constraining yourself to integer, but a WAG would be that's what's overflowing.)

Answer (score 2):

Save yourself a ton of headaches and use datawindows...  You'd reduce that entire script to about 10 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Horan gave you good advice. This would be simple using DataWindows or DataStores. Terry Voth is on the right track for your problem.

In your code, Variable `l_pvds_obj_id` needs to be the same type as `gx_l_doc_obj_id` because if you get a result, it will always be equal to it. From the apparent naming scheme it was intended to be long. This is the kind of stuff we look for in peer reviews.

A few other things:
Most of the time you want SQLCode not SQLDbCode but you didn't say what database you're using.
After you UPDATE crt_script you need to check the result.
I don't see COMMIT or ROLLBACK. Autocommit isn't suitable when you need to update multiple tables.
You aren't using most of the values from the first SELECT. Perhaps you've simplified your code for posting or troubleshooting.